# Pasar informacion a php

Tags: php, javascript, html

Lo que quiero hacer es pasar unos valores que genero mediante una funcion javascript para poderlos guardar con php en una base de datos,entonces quiero pasar lo siguiente.

```
            <p>Su serial es </p>   
            <p id="SerialNumber"></p>
            <p>Su Host Name es </p>
            <p id="hostName"></p>
```

La cuestion es que esos id me le dan un valor y se imprime en pantalla,hay alguna forma de pasar esos valores a php ,para guardarlos,con metodo POST.

Gracias

Comment: Deberías incluir la función en javascript que mencionas para poder entender mejor tu pregunta.

Comment: Esos datos estan dentro del formulario que después enviarías mediante POST al PHP ?

Comment: No puedo postearla ya que es muy larga.

Comment: Quiero saber si al ponerlos dentro de un formulario los puedo enviar ,ya que probe pero sin exito.

Comment: Trabaja con el atributo name, tus elementos no los tienen y php trabaja con eso

Comment: Php también envía formularios por el método post, y no estás usándolo. Haz ese cambio más

Comment: ¿quieres enviar el valor de los id, o el texto que contienen las etiquetas <p></p>?

Comment: El texto que se generan en ls etiquetas

Answer (score 1):

Mi recomendacion es el uso de Javascript puesto que dichos valores no estan en ningun formulario. Puedes usar Javascript puro o usar alguna Framework o libreria, en este caso te pondré un ejemplo con el uso de JQuery

**MiArhivoJS.js**

```
//puedes poner un onClic y llamarlo desde un boton
function miMetodo()
{
datos = {}
datos.SerialNumber = $('#SerialNumber').attr('id')
datos.hostName= $('#hostName').attr('id')

$.ajax({
    url: '/MiArchivo.php',
    type: "POST",
    data: datos,
    success: function (response) {
      //Tus funciones en caso de que todo salga bien
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
     //Tus funciones en caso de error en servidor
    },
 });
}
```

**MiArchivo.php**

```
<?php 
$serialNumber= $_POST["SerialNumber "]
$hostName= $_POST["hostName"]
 /* Desde aqui tu puedes continuar con los métodos en la base de datos */
?>
```